# Lawn repair / treatment ahead of spring?

Tags: lawn, grass, repair

Towards the end of summer and for the whole of winter  the lawn at the back of my house has been ignored. It now looks more like a farmers field and needs some attention!

There are photos here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nh46s9xy7pyd0jz/7R5w655tU0

It's very white / yellow and is quite hard or brittle to touch. There are areas of weeds and bare patches too. I really want to get it nice for summer so my little girl can play on there. Can anyone offer any suggestions or starting points?

EDIT: Embeded some close-up photos and added more photos to the drop box link. Should be easier to see the whiteness/yellowing and the weeds etc.

[image: Close-up of bare patch.]

[image: Close of up weeds.]

Comment: Questions! How old is this lawn? Was it turf or seed, and luxury grade or utility? Have you treated it with anything in the last year, or done any maintenance at all apart from cutting? Have you had lying snow, and walked on the lawn when it was frozen/snowed over?

Comment: It's roughly 4 years old, was laid as turf, hasn't been treated, only maintenance has been cutting and has had some snow but not walked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some lawn fungus.
I would take a soil sample to a local garden center or school (if they do that in your area) and have it tested so you know where and how to start repairing.

You'll want to dethatch that lawn and start mowing it on a regular basis. Probably an aeration and over seed as well.

Unless you tear it up and replant/sod, having it repaired by summer isn't likely. Repairing that will be a process.

My first step would be the soil test, but if you don't do that consider having it aerated and over seeded with some compost and starter fertilizer. You have to start mowing that weekly (or as much as needed) about 3" in height, more if possible.

Comment: Thanks for posting after so long!  Since the OP I've been over the lawn with a scarifier and remove two 1-tonne bags of that.  The issue now if that some of the weeds in the lawn that were also suppressed by the thatch are now thriving!  Do you have any guidance on over-seeding?

Comment: From your profile - I am not sure the best seed for UK areas. I normally over-seed after aerating & mix in a small amount of mushroom compost & starter fertilizer. Have had good results with that. I'm not sure if it will help but you may want to check out corn gluten sprays?

Comment: Do you know what kind of weeds they are?

Comment: There's a few dandelions in the lawn but other than that I couldn't tell you I'm afraid. RE aeration, do I just spike the lawn with a pitchfork?

Comment: I use Scott's Weed & Feed (step 1 and 2) for dandelions. Walk around your yard with golf shoes is a cheap way to aerate - but if I was you I would actually rent a core aerator - it will tear up the yard and it into a good mess, but it recovers fairly quickly. It basically allows oxygen into the root systems and breaks up the soil for the root systems to expand easier.

Comment: I'm actually going to add one more comment to this - What  core aeration will do is actually cut a 'plug' (round cylinder shape) of soil from  your lawn. It is meant to loosen up the soil, allow roots room to grow, and oxygen to penetrate. Don't do it too often because  it is damaging to the turf  grass - it needs time to heal. While poking holes work to get  oxygen in - it also compacts the soil more around  the  hole you poked - so it is a win/lose situation. Good luck.